# two foreach in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

...I've tried something but I got the "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." exception.
I'm talking about this:

```
Query = Query.Where(t => this.SysTextBox.Text.CSL2Array().All(ss => t.SysName.Contains(ss)));
```

I'm kind of new at this, but I kept trying to make it work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `CSL2Array`?

Comment: Oh. It just returns an array with the words from  SubSystemTextBox.Text. It splits the string by comma.

Comment: And obviously that can't be translated into SQL code by the query provider.  You need to not be doing that inside of the expression, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Got that. So I can't do this with linq.

Comment: You can't do that specific operation with LINQ, that doesn't mean you can't do any of the rest of it with LINQ.  Your original solution has a *ton* of problems with it, ranging from iterating the sequence several times, doing all of the work application side instead of any of it being done on the database side, the false impression that the returned queryable can be further refined without being evaluated, doing tons of linear searches through large collections when searching/removing, re-computing values all over the place, and so on.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'll leave this for later on then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the query after `ToList`:

```
Query = Query.ToList<TagsDeleted>()
             .Where(t => this.SubSystemTextBox.Text.CSL2Array().All(ss => t.SubsystemName.Contains(ss)))
             .AsQueryable<TagsDeleted>();
```

But that is not easy to read, I would refactor to the following to make it clear that "I create a list, and want to remove some items":

```
var words = this.SubSystemTextBox.Text.CSL2Array();
var list = Query.ToList<TagsDeleted>();
list.RemoveAll(t => !words.All(word => t.SubsystemName.Contains(word)));
Query = list.AsQueryable<TagsDeleted>();
```

Comment: So ToList can do this. This is what I was looking for, thank you !! :)

Comment: It's probably faster when you use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = this.SubSystemTextBox.Text.CSL2Array();
var notContained = Query.Where(td=>arr.Any(ss => !td.SubsystemName.Contains(ss)));
Query = Query.Except(notContained);
```

You can figure this out how to make it in one line, this was just to be clear.

Comment: Again, "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." :(

Comment: But yes, that is what I'm trying to do.